# Find a function whose domain and range do not contain any positive numbers

Tags: analysis

Find a function whose domain and range do not contain any positive numbers. Explain why your function satisfied.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
y=-( 1+\mid \ln( -1-x) \mid )\\
The\ domain\ is\ ( -\infty ,-1)\\
and\ the\ range\ is\ ( -\infty ,-1) .
\end{gather*}
Does this answer your question?